# Local Variable 'X' Referenced Before Assignment in Django Views

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I am working with Django and trying to create two forms on one page which I am struggling with.

I would like to know why I am getting the error "local variable 'street_address' referenced before assignment" originating from line 131 in views.

VIEWS.PY - CheckoutView Class

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = AddressForm(self.request.POST or None)
    form_2 = PaymentForm(self.request.POST or None)
    # order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
    # order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
    if all([form.is_valid(), form_2.is_valid()]):
        street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
        city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
        postcode = form.cleaned_data.get('postcode')
        country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
        state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
        shipping_method = form.cleaned_data.get('shipping_method')
        card_num = form.cleaned_data.get('card_num')
        cvc = form.cleaned_data.get('cvc')
        exp_date = form.cleaned_data.get('exp_date')

    address = Shipping(
        user=self.request.user,
        street_address=street_address,
        city=city,
        postcode=postcode,
        country=country,
        state=state,
        shipping_method=shipping_method
    )

    card_details = Payment(
        user=self.request.user,
        card_num=card_num,
        cvc=cvc,
        exp_date=exp_date
    )

    address.save()
    card_details.save()
    return render(self.request,"Order_Management/checkout.html")'''
```

Comment: If both forms aren't valid, the `street_address` variable doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are checking to see if the forms are valid.. and if they are, you fetch the values from them and assign them to variables.

But, the part of your code where you construct your `Shipping` and `Payment` models and save them is executed every time, it's not indented within the block where you checked the validity of the forms.

The result is that if either form is invalid, your code will try to construct the models anyway, and it won't be able to because you haven't assigned the variables from the forms.

So you need to indent all that code as well so it's all under your validity check.

```
if all([form.is_valid(), form_2.is_valid()]):
    street_address = form.cleaned_data.get('street_address')
    city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
    postcode = form.cleaned_data.get('postcode')
    country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
    state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
    shipping_method = form.cleaned_data.get('shipping_method')
    card_num = form.cleaned_data.get('card_num')
    cvc = form.cleaned_data.get('cvc')
    exp_date = form.cleaned_data.get('exp_date')

    address = Shipping(
        user=self.request.user,
        street_address=street_address,
        city=city,
        postcode=postcode,
        country=country,
        state=state,
        shipping_method=shipping_method
    )

    card_details = Payment(
        user=self.request.user,
        card_num=card_num,
        cvc=cvc,
        exp_date=exp_date
    )

    address.save()
    card_details.save()

return render(self.request,"Order_Management/checkout.html")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! The information isn't appearing in django admin 'payments' though, would you know why that is at all? Really appreciate your help. Shipping info is fine.

Comment: Well, probably one of your forms are not passing validation, so it's not trying to save anything.  You should really be using a FormView for this which handles most of this logic for you.  The way you are doing this, you're responsible for re-displaying the form along with any validation errors.  But what you're doing is just displaying a rendered template with no context.. so any error information is lost.